# How to find files whose name starts with "a"?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I know I'm missing something obvious and I'm certain it's to do with my -name part.

And it is homework, but I think I'm pretty close to the correct answer. Better ways of writing are always appreciated too!

```
find /home/caine/thecopy -user caine -size -10240c -name ^a.* | wc
```

This gives a `wc` of `0 0 0`, removing the name expression gives oodles of counts.

I've tried ^a , '^a' , '^a.*' and all come up with 0 results. TIA folks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the file name:

```sh
find /home/caine/thecopy -user caine -size -10240c -name "a.*" | wc
#                                                        ^   ^
```

Comment: I think it does not need the `^` (unless it is part of the filename)

Comment: +1, Otherwise the expression expands to filenames beginning with `a` in the current working directory.

Comment: Regarding your comment, @user000001, he may need the `^` in case he wants files to start with `a`...

Comment: @fedorqui I just tested it here and with `^` it matches nothing. Without it matches anything that begins with `a.`. Maybe its just my bash version.

Comment: Ops, that's interesting @user000001! I do not have a shell here with me, so I will edit my answer to the one you suggest and tomorrow will check. Thanks for letting me know : )

Comment: @fedorqui: I believe you've missed the real issue; see my answer. But yes, the quotation marks are also important.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to `-name` is a shell pattern, *not* a regular expression.  The `^` and `.` characters will match literal `^` and `.` characters, not the beginning of the name and any character, respectively, as they would if it were a regular expression.

If you want to match file names starting with `'a'`, this should work:

```
find /home/caine/thecopy -user caine -size -10240c -name 'a*' | wc
```

The quotation marks around `a*` (either single or double) are important; without them, the shell will expand the pattern before `find` sees it.

If you really want to match a regular expression, you can replace `-name` with `-regex`; that's a GNU-specific extension. But in this case, a shell pattern is probably good enough.

Note: I'm assuming that you want to match files whose names start with `a`; you didn't actually say so.

Comment: Bingo! Yep, I'm still mis-using where and when to use regexp characters. :/

  Many thanks for your help guys. :)